# Decision to go for SPA or multi-page architecture

Tags: user-experience, single-page-application

Following question is pretty much an architecture level question, please bear with me and give me some feedback:

How do you take the decision whether you want to go for a SPA or traditional multi-page level application? Is there any factors that you should consider before you decide to go for SPA approach? I'm sure you just not think you want to give your users a rich user experience by reducing server round trips and just go in the SPA way.

I'm really trying to understand what should be considered before taking that decision and hope someone could answer me.

Thanks in advance